# How can I break out of two nested for loops in Objective-C?

Tags: c, objective-c, loops

I have two for loops nested like this:

```
for(...) {
    for(...) {

    }
}
```

I know that there is a `break` statement. But I am confused about if it breaks both loops or just the one in which it was called? I need to break both ones as soon as I see that it doesn't make sense to iterate more times over.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

break breaks out of one loop, but you can add a check to the outer loop which breaks when the inner breaks.

```
bool dobreak = false;
for ( ..; !dobreak && ..; .. ) {
   for ( ... ) {
      if (...) {
         dobreak = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, using goto is much cleaner.

Comment: `!dobreak` is in the wrong place; it should go in the conditional (for's second part) rather than the increment step (for's third part); I would also use `!dobreak && ..`, so that the other conditions do not need to be evaluated when breaking.  I agree with sigjuice: `goto` is not evil when used properly, and this is a case where `goto` *does* make for better code.

Comment: This would still execute possible code in the outer loop that would come after the inner loop

Comment: @Martijn - this can be addressed by replacing the `break` with a `continue` statement. Still, it's just more non-obvious stuff to worry about.

Answer (score 109):

If using goto simplifies the code, then it would be appropriate.

```
for (;;) 
{
    for (;;) 
    {
        break; /* breaks inner loop */
    } 
    for (;;) 
    {
        goto outer; /* breaks outer loop */
    }
} 
outer:;
```

Comment: To expand on this, `for (;;) {for (;;) {break; /* breaks inner loop */} for (;;) {goto outer; /* breaks outer loop */}} outer:;`

Comment: (;;) looks like a little face.

Answer (score 14):

The `break` statement only gets you out of the innermost loop. If you don't want the added overhead in code, memory and performance of a dedicated state variable, I recommend refactoring the code out into a function or method of its own, and using `return` to get out of all the loops:

```
void do_lots_of_work(void)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i=0; i<10 ; i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j< 10; j++)
    {
     ..
     ..
     if(disaster_struck())
      return; /* Gets us out of the loops, and the function too. */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd be very surprised if a function call in a loop managed to perform as well as a dedicated state variable, especially if you need to pass arguments in order to have access to variables in the outer function.  Maybe if the compiler copies the function inline...

Comment: What's worse, in my opinion, is the loss of the ability to understand the algorithm by reading it in one place. All this to avoid a goto?

Comment: I've run into this break/continue problem as well, sometimes wanting to continue the loop 2-3 levels up.  Best thing to do IMHO is to refactor the nested loops into a method so that method can return whether to continue to parent loop.

Comment: what if the user wants to exit only the loop and not the function?

Comment: This is the best solution, in my opinion. It's unambiguous what happens, it's easy to control, it's easy to call, it doesn't allocate & evaluate an unnecessary boolean, and it doesn't use dangerous old practices like `goto`. Performance concerns should also be non-notable in any real-world use.

Comment: @OriPessach if you name this method very well, then it's easy to understand what's happening. Your argument places raw assembly above Objective-C as a better language (since it puts everything in one place), which goes against the point of the question.

Comment: @AkshayJ Then place the after-outer-loop code after this method is called

Answer (score 9):

Other than the already mentioned flag variable or goto you could [throw](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html) an Objective-C exception:

```
@try {
  for() {
    for() {
       @throw ...
    }
  }
}
@catch{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, just as I was about to modify my answer to point out how people will suggest every single convoluted solution except using exceptions for flow control just to avoid a goto...

Comment: @Ori Pessach Well Exceptions are the modern OO versions of goto ;-)

Comment: They do clean up the stack nicely, at least.

Comment: In my experiences exceptions are very very slow and should not be used to handle execution flow.

Comment: Do some research on exceptions in ObjC.  In the Apple docs they specifically that performance hit is big and they say, "The Cocoa frameworks are generally not exception-safe. The general pattern is that exceptions are reserved for programmer error only, and the program catching such an exception should quit soon afterwards."

Answer (score 7):

Others have mentioned how you can set a flag or use a `goto`, but I'd recommend refactoring your code so that the inner loop is turned into a separate method.  That method can then return some flag to indicate that the outer loop should `break`.  If you name your methods appropriately, this is much more readable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (timeToStop(i)) break;
}

-(bool) timeToStop: (int) i {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (somethingBadHappens) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Pseudocode, not tested, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

The break statement will only break out of the loop in scope, which is the parent loop. If you want to break out of the second loop as well you could use a boolean variable which is in scope of both loops

```
bool isTerminated = false;

for (...)
{
    if (!isTerminated)
    {
        for(...)
        {
            ...

            isTerminated = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to use a "flag" variable

```
for(i=0; i<10 && (done==false); i++)
  for(j=0;j< 10; j++){
     ..
     ..
     if(...){done=true; break;}
  }
```

Comment: @Jonny those are called `fast-enumeration` loops in Obj-C

Answer (score 2):

Change top loop's counter before break

```
for(i=0; i<10 ; i++)
  for(j=0;j< 10; j++){
     ..
     ..
     i = 10; 
     break;
  }
```

Comment: I don't like this too much. The risk is that someone changes the exit condition in one place, and forget the other.

Comment: `NSUInteger limit = 10;`  Then: `for(i=0; i<limit; i++) { for(j=0; j<10; j++) { .. .. i = limit; break; } }`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to factor out the second loop in a function:

```
int i;

for(i=0; i<10 ; i++){
    if !innerLoop(i) {
        break;
    }
}

bool innerLoop(int i)
    int j;
    for(j=0;j< 10; j++){
        doSomthing(i,j);
        if(endcondtion){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The break statement breaks out of the innermost loop.  An additional test and break statement would be needed to break out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

If a break is executed from within a set of nested loops, only the innermost loop in which the break is executed is terminated. (Just like standard C)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like the last ones are, generally like this:

```
for(i=0;i<a;i++){  
 for(j=0;j<a;j++){
  if(Something_goes_wrong){
   i=a;
   break;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins, how about changing this true/false check into a method and using `return` statements:

```
- (bool) checkTrueFalse: parameters{

   for ( ...) {
      for ( ... ) {

         if (...) {
            return true;
         }

      }
   }
   return false;
}
```