# Is there any C# decompiler that can show the coding almost identically to how it was written?

Tags: c#, decompiling

I've been using reflector to decompile a couple simple c# apps but I notice that though code is being decompiled, I still can't see things as they were written on VS. I think this is the way it is as the compiler replaces human instructions by machine code. However I thought I would give it a try and ask it on here. Maybe there is a decompiler that can decompile and show the coding almost identically to the original code.

Comment: "Almost" counts in horse shoes and hand grenades.  Decompilers blow up when trying to decompile iterators, anonymous methods and lambda expressions.  And some more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542289/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-use-goto-in-modern-net-code/2542437#2542437  Decompiling code comments doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is impossible, since there are lots of ways to get the same IL from different code. For example, there is no way to know if an extension method was called fluent-style vs explicit on the declaring type. There is no way to know if LINQ vs regular code was used. All manner of implicit operations may or may not be there. Removed code may or may not have been there. Many primitives (including enums) up-to-and-including 4 bytes are indistinguishable once they are IL.

If you want the actual code, legally obtain the original code.

Answer (score 5):

Existing .Net decompilers generally decompile to the best of their ability.

You appear to be asking for variable names and line formatting, which for obvious reasons are not compiled to IL.

Comment: "..not compiled to IL" - Actually they usually are, one needs to actively obfuscate to eliminate variable names. (In some cases variable names are lost, perhaps due to Release Mode optimisations and/or compiler generated variables/code).

Comment: @Todd: I don't think that's true, except for the PDB file.

Comment: I could be wrong, perhaps only class, method, (and parameter names are persisted in the dll) - however I recall finding variables to be decompiled without pdb file. On the same token, I have also decompiled and found the decompiler making up variable names such as 'test' and 'string'. Perhaps this was a debug dll, or perhaps I'm completely wrong.

Comment: @Todd Local variable names aren't persisted - but the decompiler can guess at the name quite well in some cases (e.g. the return value of a method). Arguments, class and member names, constants... all those are still present in IL, since .NET is designed for easy interop - named locals don't help that a bit.

Comment: Also, locals that are lifted to closure classes (for async, lambdas, or iterators) become fields, so their names are persisted.

Comment: @Luaan, Yes, you are right. It must only be member variables of classes which are retained being reflectable.

Answer (score 2):

There are several. I currently use JustDecompile found here http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=sm&utm_campaign=ad

**[Edit]**
An alternative is .NET Reflector found here: http://www.reflector.net/
I believe there is a free version of it, but didn't take time to look.

Comment: reflector is no longer free. there is an older version that was free, that was before the product was bought out by redgate.

Comment: There *was* a free version -- you can only get it now if you had a copy of the old versions. I still have a copy but I don't think they want me to distribute it lol. (Not sure if it goes against the license or not, though, since it used to be free.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no. There are often many ways to arrive at the same IL code, and there's no way at all for a decompiler to know which was used.

Answer (score 1):

No, nor should there ever be. Things like comments and unreachable code would just add bloat with absolutely zero benefit. The very best you can ever do is approximate the compiled code.