# How I can Decompile .dll file code and comment

Tags: c#, dll, comments, reverse-engineering

i have a .dll file that written in c#
so i need to decompile .dll file to code with comment ??
I have tried many programs like (JustDecompile , dotpeek , ILSpy) but all of them are decompiling file with out comment.

Comment: The compiler optimizes the code per default which means that e.g. comments will be deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any C# decompiler that can show the coding almost identically to how it was written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379204/is-there-any-c-sharp-decompiler-that-can-show-the-coding-almost-identically-to-h)

Answer (score 0):

For the full information you need a corresponding `xml` file for xml documentation, and a `.pdb` symbol file containing the metadata.

Without it  you can "decompile", but you might find yourself having a hard time.

Note: the full info `pdb` is usually only provisioned with a debug version of the assembly. If you have an external dll, its not likely it will match.