# iphone: How to stop incremental variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application I chose one integer type variable name counter.

```
int counter;
```

which is used to increase different values.
but in some condition I want to stop the increasing value

```
if (counter > totalImageCount) {
            NSLog(@"counter:%d",counter);
            counter = counter - 8;
}
```

and I don't have any idea how to stop the value of this counter.
In above if condition I want to add one more condition like if the value of the counter = 100 at that time I want to stop the counter
but I don't know how to stop the counter.
plz tell me how can I stop

Comment: Where do you increase your counter? Post notification or set global variable indicating that increasing should stop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for something like this;

```
bool dobreak = false;
for ( ..; !dobreak && ..; .. ) {
   for ( ... ) {
      if (...) {
         dobreak = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

From [How can I break out of two nested for loops in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863172/how-can-i-break-out-of-two-nested-for-loops-in-objective-c)

Comment: but I don't have any kind of loop so I can't use break; statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use one more if condition inside your if block like:

```
if (counter > totalImageCount) {
     if( counter >100)
          break;
     NSLog(@"counter:%d",counter);
     counter = counter - 8;
}
```

or you can use `if(counder>totalImageCount  && counter<100)`